# How can I generate a covariance matrix with specified correlation coefficient?

Tags: matrices, covariance

I know it is easy to get a 2$\times$2 covariance matrix by specifying correlation coefficient $\rho\in[-1,1]$, as $\sigma_{12}=\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2$. Since $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are scalar, I can easily get the cross-correlation.

However, what if the covariance is $4\times4$? What I mean is, I have two covariance matrices of $2\times2$. I want to generate the cross-correlation between them for all degree of correlation.

If I simply vary the 4 correlation coefficients (the relations between 2 varibles is 4), does this make a valid covariance? I would expect that cov(x1,x3) and cov(x2,x4) are related because of cov(x1,x2).

Demonstration in Matlab will do.

Comment: What you are asking is: given 2 by 2 symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$, what are the 2 by 2 matrices $C$ so that $\begin{bmatrix} A & C \\ C^T & B \end{bmatrix}$ is positive semi-definite.  I don't see a really easy answer beyond computing the determinants of the upper left $k$ by $k$ submatrices.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Yes, that's what I want. Do you mean "computing the determinants of the upper right $2\times2$" submatrices? Can you give more hint about that method?

Comment: No.  You have to compute the determinants of the upper left $1\times 1$ matrix, the upper left $2 \times 2$ matrix, the upper left $3\times 3$ matrix, and the whole thing.